# Log4j2 JsonTemplateLayout - log message field as json

Tags: log4j2

I have this `log4j2.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
<Appenders>
    <Console name="JsonAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:EcsLayout.json" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="JsonLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="JsonAppender"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="JsonAppender"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

In my code I have a logging statement like:

```
HashMap logMap = new HashMap<>();
        logMap.put("appId", "123456789");
        logMap.put("action", "Received request");

        logger.info(new ObjectMessage(logMap));
```

In my log I get this:

```
 {
        "@timestamp": "2022-02-02T10:52:56.100Z",
        "ecs.version": "1.2.0",
        "log.level": "INFO",
        "message": "{appId=123456789, action=Received request}",
        "process.thread.name": "main",
        "log.logger": "org.xxxx.App" 
}
```

That's ok but I want the `message` to be in json, so would like:

```
"message": {
              "appId": "123456789", 
              "action": "Received request"
}
```

I know using `JsonLayout` you had to specify `objectMessageAsJsonObject="true"`, but suspect it's a bit more nuanced when using `JsonTemplateLayout`.

TIA.

Answer (score 3):

Upon reading the [JSON Template Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html) docs further, you can modify the event template fields by leveraging the `eventTemplateAdditionalField` param.

There seems to be a few ways to approach this but the option I went with is to modify the `log4j2.xml`:

```
<Appenders>
        <Console name="JsonAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:LambdaEcsLayout.json">
                <EventTemplateAdditionalField
                        key="message"
                        format="JSON"
                        value='{"$resolver": "message", "field": "name"}'/>/>
            </JsonTemplateLayout>

        </Console>
    </Appenders>
```

And when logging, have something like this:

```
var logMap = new HashMap<>();
        logMap.put("id", "123456789");
        logMap.put("action", "Received request");
        var om = new ObjectMessage(logMap);

        log.info(om);
```

There is probably a much neater way to deal with the latter, some kind of wrapper etc - but you get the idea.

Comment: Nice. Worked for me.

Comment: Mmm, on review this doesn't work for me.  It does not work for me with some arbitrary object e.g. I get `"message":{"x":{"a":"b"},"p":"com.xyz.Person@3132fc"}` x is a map and is fine. p is a bean and is wrong but works file using jsonLayout.

Why is all this so hard? It is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get @Hurricane's method to work, but in trying to simplify it, I found that you can omit the <EventTemplateAdditionalField> element and add

```
"message": {
    "$resolver": "message",
    "stringified": false
}
```

to the template layout instead.  You can also omit the 'stringified' attribute as it defaults to 'false'. The OP didn't include the layout, but I suspect he had 'stringified' set to 'true'